# Spring security custom filter called twice for REST Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-filter

I implemented a custom Spring Security Filter to have a custom Authentication system. This works fine.

To configure my filter I used this config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http.antMatcher("/api/**")
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated().and().addFilterBefore(new MyTokenAuthFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
```

If I try to put a breakpoint into this filter I see that the method doFilterInternal will be called twice for each REST request.
Strange.. Any suggestion?

Comment: A bit random, but: Any chance you are using Chrome? Or are these real REST requests?

I think it has to do with Chrome's site pre-fetch. I had the same problem during a couple of workshops recently, and could reliably reproduce it in Chrome, but not the other browsers.

Comment: @MarcoBehler I'm in Debug mode using POSTMAN as res client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem I found the cause:

I declared my custom filter as @Component.

This is not necessary and this will produce a twofold filter registration in my case.